How to use foreach in Ajax GET method?
I have a problem. For a calendar, I would like to display appointments that belong to the logged-in user with details, while all other appointments in the database should be grayed out.
The is the table












App. 1
user 1
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code


App. 2
user 2
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code


App. 3
user 3
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code


App. 4
user 1
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code



User1 is logged in and would see the appointments as follows:












App. 1
user 1
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code


App. 2

06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00



App. 3

06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00



App. 4
user 1
06/15/2024 8:00
06/15/2024 9:00
Test the code



In my view I display the calendar using Fullcalendar.io, the events are loaded in the eventSources section, written in ajax. I would now say a foreach loop with the user query, if yes, then show everything, if no, then only show the date and time, field color then gray. However, I am not that well versed in Ajax, I get the data via the GET method, like this:
eventSources: [
    {
        url: '/Calendar/GetEvents',
        method: 'GET',
        failure: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        color: 'orange',
        textColor: 'black'
    }
]

How can I now insert a foreach loop? Getevents is the array with the appointments, so I would have to open it differently.
BR
Sven

To do this you need to use success callback
for example:
success: function(response) {
  var events = [];

  // Assuming 'response' is an array of event objects
  response.forEach(function (event) {
    if (event.userId === loggedInUserId) {
      // Event belongs to the logged-in user, show full details
      events.push({
        title: event.title,
        start: event.start,
        end: event.end,
        color: 'orange',
        textColor: 'black'
      });
    } else {
     // Event does not belong to the logged-in user, show only date and time
        events.push({
          title: '',
          start: event.start,
          end: event.end,
          color: 'gray',
          textColor: 'white'
        });
      }
    });

    // Call the success callback with the events array
    successCallback(events);
 }


Hi Reda, sounds good, I will try your solution and report the result. :-)
